Do tech companies like Microsoft & CrowdStrike face almost no legal liabilities for major disruptions?
In regards to a widespread technology meltdown, reportedly caused by Microsoft and CrowdStrike, the New York Times states that the "immediate and harmful" impact included:

Airlines canceled flights and airports fell into chaos in the United States, Europe and Asia.

In the United States, operators of 911 lines in multiple states could not respond to emergencies.

Parts of Britain’s National Health Service reported problems.

New driver’s licenses could not be issued in some areas.

Some television broadcasters could not go on the air.


The above referenced article claims that the economic and legal penalties are so trivial that companies like Microsoft and CrowdStrike have almost no legal incentive to change their apparently flawed practices and designs:

The outages underscored an uncomfortable reality that software companies face few liabilities for major disruptions and cybersecurity incidents. The economic and legal penalties for such significant outages can be so minimal that companies are not motivated to make more fundamental changes. While a car manufacturer would face stiff penalties for faulty brakes, a software provider can often issue another update and move on.
Thomas Parenty is a cybersecurity consultant and a former U.S. National Security Agency analyst.
“Until software companies have to pay a price for faulty products, we will be no safer tomorrow than we are today,” Mr. Parenty said.

Is this assertion correct, that companies have almost no legal incentive (criminal or civil) to not harm other corporations, or the general public, with defective or poorly designed software?
The jurisdiction of this question is global, given that companies like these typically provide tech services globally.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Preface: the disruption was not caused by Microsoft, that was just the platform being used (along CrowdStrike Falcon) by the affected entities. It's completely normal that Microsoft Windows may crash when using a faulty driver. It's also acceptable for Falcon to use a driver for its intended purpose. What is not acceptable is the CrowdStrike published an update with a broken driver which crashes the hosts.
You cannot claim directly to CrowdStrike a liability for those actions. The onus is on those that directly provide the service.

In the United States, operators of 911 lines in multiple states could not respond to emergencies.

This is a big failure by the 911 lines if they are not able to function. They must have crisis plans for contingencies so the service continues being given (typically, the service is redirected to a different call-center). On the other hand, an individual center not working is per se not a problem, as long as the service itself is provided (I don't know if they then bill one another, but that's up to them to resolve later).

Some television broadcasters could not go on the air.

Here television broadcasters suffer the loses directly.

Airlines canceled flights and airports fell into chaos in the United States, Europe and Asia.

(note: some airlines were not affected at all, and this may be a bit of exaggeration, but let's go along with it)
This is a problem of the airlines and/or airports. If you had a flight canceled, the airline should compensate you (not CrowdStrike). Note that the airline chose to use this product exclusively (thus creating such risk if that product failed). Moreover, they would have had no alternative system should their systems go down (e.g. some people got hand-written boarding passes).
Maybe some of these companies might be able to pass those losses to CrowdStrike, depending on their license agreements. Or they might fully bear the responsibility of failing to provide their service when CrowdStrike failed. Also note that, depending on which systems they deployed this agent, their number, the count of IT people they employed and how spread out their systems were, the time to recovery would vary significantly.
These companies made a number of decisions (which were quite reasonable, by the way) which turned our to lead to a bad outcome on a failure from CrowdStrike. That has caused them an important financial loss on this day (and they may continue having to refund customers, etc).
CrowdStrike itself, while not liable to the people with cancelled flights or who didn't had their driver license issued, will face claims from their clients. Moreover, after this enormous failure in checking their release, a number of clients will switch to a different solution, reducing their income. Their shares have already fallen 20%. Plus, they have suffered a really big dark mark on their brand, and it will be much harder for them to attract new clients.
Despite not having a direct legal liability for these events, this won't be cheap at all for CrowdStrike.

This seems to be claiming that liabilities just vanish the moment more than 2 parties are involved. This is false in general, there are some special rules for software so that software companies are not liable for their product the same way every other company is. If I book a plane ticket from an airline and the flight is cancelled because of some problem with the airplane, then I have a claim against the airline and the airline has a claim agains the aircraft manufacturer. If the flight is cancelled because the airline bought faulty software no one is liable for anything.

@quarague There aren't special legal rules for the liability of software/online service providers in general. There may be special rules for airline liability.

@ohwilleke No special legal rules, true. But if I buy a physical good in general I don't have to sign any terms and conditions and I have some kind of legal guarantee that the product is suitable for the purpose it is advertised for. If I buy software I have to sign terms and conditions and if the software doesn't work as advertised that is my problem. Technically all covered by contractual freedom but the general standards on what is common and considered normal are very different.

@quarague "f I buy a physical good in general I don't have to sign any terms and conditions and I have some kind of legal guarantee that the product is suitable for the purpose it is advertised for." It isn't at all unusual for their to be waivers of liability and disclaimers in the sale of goods as well.

I don't think it affects the question of liability, but I disagree with the characterisation in the first paragraph "It's completely normal that Microsoft Windows may crash when using a faulty driver." - if I replace "normal" with "acceptable" (after all, anything can be normal) then I think there is room for reasonable disagreement here. There are easy ways Windows could prevent this sort of mistake from taking down a whole machine.

@quarague: You'll find that airline companies do need to sign T&Cs when they buy airplanes. The physical nature of the good is irrelevant, but the complexity is. Software is more complex than a T shirt.

@preferred_anon: CrowdStrike is malware protection. Taking down a computer might be reasonable in order to prevent the spread of malware in a company; at least in this instance Microsoft cannot be blamed. Also, Windows can't prevent these mistakes because these drivers are by design part of the running kernel. Windows can only check them when loading them, and that check did pass - it was a real CrowdStrike driver, not a fake.

@MSalters - Your second reason is the right one.  Windows wasn't considering the intended function of CrowdStrike when deciding to crash down.  But it's true that antivirus products generally choose to run as kernel drivers on Windows (and that they partly do that to protect themselves from malware interference), thus forgoing some error protections than the OS can extend to ordinary processes.

@MSalters "Taking down a computer might be reasonable" - might be reasonable deliberately, but is completely unreasonable by mistake. It is not hard to imagine ways Windows could have rolled back or rescued in case of a crash, if the interface to drivers were designed better. Allowing kernel code to update itself with no oversight and no mitigation in case of bugs is shoddy IMO. If someone drives a car into a bridge and the bridge is damaged, you sue the driver; if someone drive a car into a bridge and the bridge collapses, you sue the builder.

@preferred_anon: There are ways to roll back in the event of a crash; that's how you recover from stuff like this. But auto-diagnosing kernel issues is a near impossible task. Kernel mode stuff has complete access to the entire memory space; even if you can identify where something went wrong, there is no way to be sure the problem wasn't another kernel module writing garbage to the location that failed. Windows has user-mode drivers, the better interface you're asking for, but anti-malware stuff stays kernel layer to have the privileges to fight malware (which doesn't play by the rules).

The short answer is that liability is universally waived contractually in software licensing agreements.
As noted in a comment from Jen, "the customers (e.g. passengers) of the directly harmed entity (e.g. an airline) cannot generally claim against the software providers because of the principle of non-recovery for relational economic loss."
Waivers of liability for ordinary negligence, or for strict liability in tort, are normally effective. Waivers of liability for intentional conduct or conduct that is carried out in bad faith (e.g. if the software company deliberately tried to sabotage your company) are not valid.
The law is not quite as uniform on whether conduct that constitutes gross negligence, is reckless, or is willful and wanton can waived. Some jurisdictions do not allow this either. But if a simple screw up causes a huge amount of harm, this doesn't make the mistake "gross negligence". These standards of mens rea involve disregard of a clear and serious risk that was known or that any reasonable person would have been patently aware of, without actually having any desire to harm someone.
There are some statutory liabilities that cannot be waived because a statute says so. But for the most part, the kinds of liabilities to which software companies are exposed when their software goes wrong are not as a result of statutory liabilities that expressly remove the ability to waive those liabilities by statute.
Also, sometimes, even when a contractual waiver is not fully effective to eliminate all liability, it may be effective to limit the damages that may be imposed in the event of a breach of a legal duty. For example, a contractual waiver might limit liability to the amount paid by the consumer or exclude consequential damages, even when it can't totally eliminate its liability.
Certainly, governments in the U.S. and elsewhere have the legal authority to prohibit waivers of liability in particular situations. This isn't the default rule, but it also isn't uncommon (especially outside the U.S.). But, so far, legislatures have largely declined to enact legislation of this kind.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Section 8.6 of the Crowdstrike Terms and Conditions reads

Disclaimer. EXCEPT FOR THE EXPRESS WARRANTIES IN THIS SECTION 8,
CROWDSTRIKE AND ITS AFFILIATES DISCLAIM ALL OTHER WARRANTIES, WHETHER
EXPRESS, IMPLIED, STATUTORY OR OTHERWISE. TO THE MAXIMUM EXTENT
PERMITTED UNDER APPLICABLE LAW, CROWDSTRIKE AND ITS AFFILIATES AND
SUPPLIERS SPECIFICALLY DISCLAIM ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, TITLE, AND
NON-INFRINGEMENT WITH RESPECT TO THE OFFERINGS AND CROWDSTRIKE TOOLS.
THERE IS NO WARRANTY THAT THE OFFERINGS OR CROWDSTRIKE TOOLS WILL BE
ERROR FREE, OR THAT THEY WILL OPERATE WITHOUT INTERRUPTION OR WILL
FULFILL ANY OF CUSTOMER’S PARTICULAR PURPOSES OR NEEDS. THE OFFERINGS
AND CROWDSTRIKE TOOLS ARE NOT FAULT-TOLERANT AND ARE NOT DESIGNED OR
INTENDED FOR USE IN ANY HAZARDOUS ENVIRONMENT REQUIRING FAIL-SAFE
PERFORMANCE OR OPERATION. NEITHER THE OFFERINGS NOR CROWDSTRIKE TOOLS
ARE FOR USE IN THE OPERATION OF AIRCRAFT NAVIGATION, NUCLEAR
FACILITIES, COMMUNICATION SYSTEMS, WEAPONS SYSTEMS, DIRECT OR INDIRECT
LIFE-SUPPORT SYSTEMS, AIR TRAFFIC CONTROL, OR ANY APPLICATION OR
INSTALLATION WHERE FAILURE COULD RESULT IN DEATH, SEVERE PHYSICAL
INJURY, OR PROPERTY DAMAGE. Customer agrees that it is Customer’s
responsibility to ensure safe use of an Offering and the CrowdStrike
Tools in such applications and installations. CROWDSTRIKE DOES NOT
WARRANT ANY THIRD PARTY PRODUCTS OR SERVICES.

Here they say that their software isn't error free and they say that they don't guarantee that it'll do anything useful. They even state that the software shouldn't be used in life critical systems like air control systems.
They also state that it's always up to the customer to ensure that it works as it should.
These are terms that their customers agree to.
The unfortunate and surprising thing, imo, in this incident is, that there are so many companies that install software on critical infrastructure that auto-updates without the companies ensuring that the machines will keep working.
All software has errors and if auto-updating is a general practice then it's a miracle that something like this doesn't happen more often.

I wonder who is responsible for all these systems that are blue screening and causing "DEATH, SEVERE PHYSICAL INJURY, OR PROPERTY DAMAGE"?

I have asked a question in relation to this answer.

My lawyer once told me that a contract doesn't necessarily mean what it says: it means what a court says that it says. In some jurisdictions, any attempt to sidestep consumer law may be interpreted by the courts as conspiracy, which can prove more serious than merely accepting the original penalties.

@SimonCrase That's ofc absolutely correct. Jurisdiction also matters a lot. As for consumer protection regulations, this contract is between corporations and consumer protection rules, in general, don't apply to corporations.

I think this answer raises an important point indeed: there's another intermediate here, and that's the company's own system administrators. System administrators letting software automatically update without checking that it doesn't disrupt the company's business? There's an argument for negligence, here.

Note that custom licensing is common in (large) business situations.

I find particularly interesting that the list of "NEITHER THE OFFERINGS NOR CROWDSTRIKE TOOLS ARE FOR USE IN THE OPERATION OF" items seems to cover all of the types of systems whose failures were newsworthy: aircraft navigation, air traffic control, communication systems, direct or indirect life support systems. Basically, the airlines, 911 facilities, television broadcasters, and perhaps the NHS (don't know enough about the impact of that one to say for certain) should never have placed Crowdstrike onto (at least some of) their systems in the first place.

It's a quid pro quo.  Suppose you want to use my software instead of employing an army of clerks using a paper system for which you would be wholly responsible.  Software is inherently more risky than clerk systems since there aren't armies of smart humans. But, it's more profitable.  That's YOUR decision to go there, not mine.
You could write it from scratch and bear total liability.  It's important to remember that.
Or, you could use my stuff.  So as a developer, my bargain with you is that if you agree to recognize the fallability of software and accept the risk for same and absolve me of it to great degree, then you have my permission to use my software.
Why does it have to be like that?  Because if I must absorb all liability for all knock-on effects which originated from use of my software, then I would be unable to obtain liability insurance and could not operate as a business, with the result that you'd have no software at all.
So that would tale you back to writing it 100% in-house, and liability would be 100% back to you anyway.
And then instead of one well-maintained shared codebase failing spectacularly for 1 day every few years, you'd have "1000 points of little failures" as the elder George Bush might say, with random websites going down every day from independent failures in their poorer-maintained codebases.  Overall it would be worse.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
